# MySql: Add "..." if result is over a certain length

Tags: mysql

I wanted to add 3 periods to a result string if the string is over 20 characters.  The result is using Group_Concat which works fine, I just don't know the best way to modify the result if over 20 chars.

query

```
LEFT(GROUP_CONCAT(employee.firstname, ' ', employee.lastname), 20) as employeenames
```

Answer (score 0):

Totally untested:

```
CASE 
    WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(GROUP_CONCAT(employee.firstname, ' ', employee.lastname))>20
    THEN CONCAT(LEFT(GROUP_CONCAT(employee.firstname, ' ', employee.lastname), 20) '...')
    ELSE GROUP_CONCAT(employee.firstname, ' ', employee.lastname)
END AS employeenames
```

It's not likely that this performs decently, though. This is the kind of stuff your client-side language will possibly do way better.

Comment: Okay, thanks for that.  I had a feeling this shouldn't be done in the query.

Comment: I guess you can also encapsulate the logic in a function.